# How does it work, the naming convention for Django INSTALLED_APPS?

Tags: python, django

The tutorial on the site creates an app named polls. It's using django 1.9, so in the INSTALLED_APPS it is:

```
polls.apps.PollsConfig
```

I'm watching a tutorial he names the app newsletter and in INSTALLED_APPS he has

```
newsletter
```

he's using 1.8, though. I am using 1.9. I've watched other tutorials and they also just add a name without dots in the syntax as he does. I realize things may be different, that's understood. To be clear if I named my app dogs,. in the installed apps it would be named like this

```
dogs.apps.DogsConfig
```

or if it was tree it would be

```
tree.apps.TreeConfig
```

Is that how the naming convention goes? also I would assume things would get shorter in newer versions and more convenient. so to go from just adding

```
newsletter,
```

to having to type out

```
polls.apps.PollsConfig
```

seems weird to me. But I'm new so I maybe missing something. Any and all advice is welcome

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That is the [*Application Configuration*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/) feature, new to Django 1.7.

Basically, now you can list in `INSTALLED_APPS` either the module that contains the application or a class that derives from `django.apps.AppConfig` and defines the behavior of the application.

This feature provides several advantages:

- Apps can be configured more easily, and even subclassed for customization.
- You can have several apps in the same module.

Application modules can define the special module variable `default_app_config` to specify the name of their `AppConfig`, so that they can use the new features without having to specify the full name of that class in `INSTALLED_APPS`. But this is a backwards compatibility feature and new applications are recommended to write the full `AppConfig` name.

Anyway, most `django/contrib` apps use that `default_app_config`, for compatibility with old configurations. See for example the file `django/contrib/messages/__init__.py` is just:

```
from django.contrib.messages.api import *
from django.contrib.messages.constants import *

default_app_config = 'django.contrib.messages.apps.MessagesConfig'
```

So, adding it up, per OP request:

- If you add in `INSTALLED_APPS` the typename `foo.apps.FooConfig`, then that class will be used to setup the `foo` app, 1.7 style (recommended).
- If you add in `INSTALLED_APPS` the plain name `foo`, then:

  - if there is a variable `foo.default_app_config` this class will be used to setup the `foo` app, 1.7 style. Most (all?) the standard Django apps have this variable, so that you don't need to change your `INSTALLED_APPS` when you upgrade from Django-1.6 to Django-1.7.
  - if there is not such a variable, then the 1.6 style application will be used, with default values for the advanced configuration options.

Comment: I'm still not clear. It would be easier for me to follow if you say "when you write 'polls.apps.PollsConfig' in INSTALLED_APPS you have access to this but if you write 'polls' in INSTALLED_APPS this.

Comment: @losee: I've added more explanation about the usage, I think that is what you requested.

Comment: after reading and rereading and some experimentation it sunk in and clicked. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In the setup.py ,under the Installed apps just add `app_name` like

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls', # <--- here
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: What does `*` do?

Comment: `*` was just highlighting the polls line, but is confusing so I will edit it out.

Comment: out of all the explainations, I found the answer in this.

Answer (score 0):

While I was searching about **INSTALLED_APPS** constant like you I have seen this explanation on documents:

A list of strings designating all applications that are enabled in this Django installation. Each string should be a dotted Python path to:

- an application configuration class (preferred), or
- a package containing an application.

The second bullet is explaining that you can use your application folder for resolving the existing settings automatically. The first option can be also used for activate your application. But the most important thing is that it is preferred one.

If you want to go with the preferred one first you have to create app.py in your new application folder then set like this:

```
# my_new_app/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyNewAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_new_app'
    verbose_name = "My Brand New Application"

# my_new_app/__init__.py
default_app_config = 'my_new_app.apps.MyNewAppConfig'
```

Why the first one is preferred? Because I think of that it is explicit.