# In Django Installed_Apps settings, what is the importance of writing "$APP_NAME.apps.$APP_NAMEConfig"?

Tags: django

I am following some of the Django courses and these courses have different formats for some specific code parts.

This is the one of them. For example, in the Installed_Apps part of settings.py, what is the difference between writing;

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django_pdb',
'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
]
```

or

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django_pdb',
'polls',
]
```

Thank you for your time and your answers.

Comment: Probably similar to - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377237/confused-a-bit-about-django-installed-apps-naming-convention

Comment: Yes, I think that would be the answer for me. Thank you @ans2human. Should I delete my question or what should I do in this case because there is already a very similar question as you sent?

Comment: As you wish, i would suggest leave it as someday someone might give us much more refined answer and then your question can become reference material for devs likes us.

Comment: ok then. thank you @ans2human