# Django declaration

Tags: django, django-settings

When declaring an App in the settings.py of the Django project is there a difference between:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   /../

    'MyAppHere',

    # AND

    'MyAppHere.apps.MyAppHereConfig',

 ]
```

Comment: I guess its already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34377341/5022847

Comment: Thanks **jonrsharpe** and **Reema Parakh** !