# Full config path vs app name in Django INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: django

In the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#configuring-applications), a line reads:

> New applications should avoid default_app_config. Instead they should require the dotted path to the appropriate AppConfig subclass to be configured explicitly in INSTALLED_APPS.

This suggests I should require users of my app (let's call it `sports`) to use the following string in their `INSTALLED_APPS` list:

```
"sports.apps.SportsConfig"
```

However, all of the Django apps I use (django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers, django-celery-results) use `default_app_config` and only require me to specify the first part of the string (in my case `"sports"`).

So how should I write my app? (1) Follow the advice in the docs and force users to write the entire string `"sports.apps.SportsConfig"` or (2) Follow what all of the other apps in the Django universe are doing and allow users to write only the first part of the string `"sports"`.

Comment: Should these popular apps be using the full config (e.g. `"rest_framework.apps.RestFrameworkConfig"`) instead of the short version (`"rest_framework"`) ?

Comment: I think you get enough for this question, see this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377237/how-does-it-work-the-naming-convention-for-django-installed-apps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it completely depends if you want to override custom default values of `Class AppConfig` for your app.

My Opinion: It's better to create **CustomAppConfig** (for eg. `sports.apps.SportsConfig`) by inheriting from Class AppConfig only for apps you create in your Django projects. Because you can tune different parameters like name, label, a verbose_name for admin panel.