# configuring installed apps in setting.py in django

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I started a project and created an app using

```
 django-admin startproject tutorial
 django-admin startapp snippets
```

Now, I am adding the "snippets" app to the **installed_apps** in **settings.py**.

but I m not able to understand the difference between:

> "snippets" and "snippets.apps.SnippetsConfig"

Which line to add in the installed_apps in settings.py file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377237/how-does-it-work-the-naming-convention-for-django-installed-apps

Comment: basically its the full name of your app (see apps.py file it contains full name of your app). Using the full name like myapp.apps.MyappConfig is when you are working on bigger projects and want to get more work done from the app (using extra features of app). But still you choose any of the two approach to name the app