# Is there a specific way of adding apps in Django

Tags: python, django

I read from a post that Django uses `INSTALLED_APPS` as a list of all of the places to look for models, management commands, tests, and other utilities.

Say I have an app called `blog` which I would like to add to `INSTALLED_APPS`, which of these two is advisable:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
]
```

OR

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
]
```

Both method seems to work fine for me as a beginner.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34377341/10860596

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial02/

You should add installed apps using the first way you have noted in your question:

```
appname.apps.AppnameConfig
```

If you open up apps.py for the application in question you will see where `AppConfig` comes from.