# What is the difference between "boards" and "boards.apps.BoardsConfig" in Django?

Tags: django, django-settings

What is the difference between "boards" and "boards.apps.BoardsConfig" in Django ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377237/how-does-it-work-the-naming-convention-for-django-installed-apps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does it work, the naming convention for Django INSTALLED\_APPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377237/how-does-it-work-the-naming-convention-for-django-installed-apps)