# What is the best way to include apps in INSTALLED_APPS, Django

Tags: python, django

We can add apps in settings.py like, let suppose my app name is *myapp*

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp.apps.AppConfig' 
     #OR
    'myapp'

]
```

I just want know to what is the difference between them? I found `myapp.apps.AppConfig`is a good practice but why?

And how can i do this in `__init__.py` file?

Comment: as starting point, head over this section **Configuring applications** from the official docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/applications/#configuring-applications

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does it work, the naming convention for Django INSTALLED\_APPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377237/how-does-it-work-the-naming-convention-for-django-installed-apps)

Comment: @rs_punia Nope!

Answer (score 2):

If you use `myapp.apps.myappConfig`, then you are explicitly telling Django to use that app config class.

Changing the app config class lets you change the behaviour of the application, for example, you can add setting file to each applications and add them to Project settting file.

On the other hand, if you just use myapp, then Django will try to use `default_app_config`.

Comment: What does it mean ```default_app_config``` ? and if we add this in ```__init__.py```, then is it also necessary to add in ```INSTALLED_APPS```?

Comment: You can set it, the deafult value of that is ```AppConfig```.

Comment: How can i set default?

Comment: set the variable default_app_config in the __init__.py file for that app